# Proof by induction - is this correct?

Tags: induction, solution-verification

Proof by induction that: For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $7^{2n}+ 2^{(2n+1)}$ is a multiple of $3$.

I think I got pretty far but I don't know if it's correct/how I should continue. My working:

Base case: show that $n=1$ holds: $7^2 + 2^3 = 57$ and $3|57$ so $n=1$ holds.

Assume that $n=k$ holds: $7^{2k}+2^{(2k+1)}$.

Prove that $n=k+1$ holds: $7^{(2k+2)} + 2^{(2k+3)}$

I rearranged this so it's in the same form as $n=k$ and got $7^2 \cdot 7^{2k} + 2^2 \cdot 2^{(2k+1)}$.

I then simplified and rearranged this to $4 \cdot 7^2k + 4 \cdot 2^{(2k+1)} + 45 \cdot 7^{2k}$.

Taking out a multiple of $4$ gives $4(7^{2k} +2^{2k+1}) + 45 \cdot 7^{2k}$ and since $(7^{2k} +2^{2k+1})$ is a multiple of $3$, I let it equal $3m$ so it's $4(3m) + 45 \cdot 7^{2k}$.

Finally, I took out a multiple of $3$ to get $3(4m + 15 \cdot 7^{2k})$ which is a multiple of $3$, hence the statement holds by induction.

Is my proof completely correct? Was there an easier way I could've done this?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Your proof looks correct

Comment: $$(7^{2n}+2^{2n+1})\bmod3=(1^{2n}+2\cdot1^n)\bmod 3.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct but too verbose. Why not just write down
$$
7^{2k+2}+2^{2k+3} = 49(7^{2k})+4(2^{2k+1})=45(7^{2k})+4(7^{2k}+2^{2k+1})
$$
and you are done.

Comment: Would I then continue the way I did by taking out a factor of 4, followed by a factor of 3?

Comment: No need. The sum of two multiples of 3 is a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for an easier way (and assuming you must use induction), consider using modular arithmetic:

For the base case for $n=1$ we have $7^{2n}+ 2^{2n+1}\equiv 1^{2n}+-1^{2n+1} \equiv 0 \pmod 3$

Then $7^{2n+2}+2^{2n+3}=7^{2}\cdot7^{2n}+4\cdot2^{2n+1}\equiv7^{2n+2}+2^{2n+1}\equiv0\pmod 3$ by hypothesis.

Although, this is a bit contrived since in this case the same can be done without needing to check the base case separately.